# Is 9th grade geometry unique in the pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangulation

I've been taking Geometry and the year is ending. I have come to realize that it is centered around the Pythagorean theorem. Is it unique in this feature or will many classes be centered around this in the future? If so, what?

Edit: when I say 'centered' I really mean fundamentally connected to and 1-2 easy 'thought' steps away.

Comment: Geometry is very interesting you gonna see topics like triangles,circle, Euler line, cyclic cuadrilater, circumference of the 9points, papus theorem, power of a cyrcle, and more topics.

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem is useful when determining the distance between 2 points.  So at any point when you want to find something that involves distance (speed, position, acceleration, height that a ladder can safely reach, etc), you'll most likely use it.

Comment: It is the primary method of determining distance in Euclidean spaces, but that is an undertone, rather than any day-to-day thing. But almost any place using geometry, it is there somewhere. You’ll rarely have to refer to the theorem directly, though.

Comment: But trigonometry is all about right triangles, so you get a lot of it there.

Comment: One of the weird places where it comes up is in statistics. In statistics, there is no reason to think the distance between two datasets is naturally Euclidean. You might think to calculate the errors in an estimate in a few ways, but the “standard deviation” is the calculated as the (scaled) square root  of the sum of squares. This might be preferred because Pythagorean distances tend to be easier to use, rather than any “natural” version. Not only does Pythagorus have geometric properties, but it has algebraic properties.

Comment: Arent these all answers?

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem is thousands of years old and has been taught this entire time because it's extremely useful in pure and applied mathematics. You should expect it to be central for the rest of your studies in any STEM field.

Comment: When you say "centered" do you actually mean "we used it more than twice and not all in the same week"? I can't imagine a 9th grade geometry class where everything ended up just being another demonstration of $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ with no other equally "central" ideas.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I really mean fundamentally connected to and 1-2 easy 'thought' steps away.

Comment: I thought the central idea of 9th grade geometry is doing proofs. The Pythagorean Theorem is something you can prove and it is one of the tools useful in proving other things, but certainly not the only tool. I don't see it in the inscribed angle theorem, for example. Of course you can construct a right triangle as a "step" in any proof and invoke Pythagoras on it, but often that would just be a wasted step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people in the best position to answer your question are the math teachers at your school, so I'd encourage you to ask (one or more of) them.

Having said that, I don't think you'll see old Pythagoras much when you come to algebra and solving equations and solving systems of equation. He'll put in more of an appearance when you get to analytic geometry and Calculus, but that theorem won't be the be-all and end-all of those subjects.

And if you make it all the way to Category Theory, you can probably wave Pythagoras goodbye.